# Alignment of UITableViewCell textLabel after removing separatorInset

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiedgeinsets

I have implemented in-line date pickers similar to how the Calendar app has implemented it, where you tap on the `UITableViewCell` and it expands the next cell underneath it which contains the `UIDatePicker`. Now I have a date picker as the last row in a section, so by default the `separatorInset` is not at `0` for the row above it, because there's another hidden cell underneath it. I need to therefore remove the separator inset by setting it to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`. But you also have to remove the `layoutMargins` for the cell that was added in iOS 8 in order to move the separator line to the far left of the table. After doing so, the cell's `textLabel` no longer aligns with the other cells' text labels - it's rendered too far left.

So how do you set the separator line to start at the far left of the table for only that one cell while also keeping its text label aligned with other cells? Note that I'm using the Right Detail cell style.

```
self.endTimeCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
self.endTimeCell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove the margins from all cells, so that they all align with that one specific cell instead of trying to make that one cell align with the others. This can be done by setting the `layoutMargins` on the entire table to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`. That may not be desirable but it does align all of the cells.

```
self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
self.endTimeCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
self.endTimeCell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```